# How to get session value in class anywhere?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have some sessions in ASP.net as follow .   In file Test.aspx.cs  have some session

```
 HttpContext.Current.Session["Id"] = obj.USER_MOD_ID;
 HttpContext.Current.Session["Group"] = obj.GROUP_MOD_ID;
 HttpContext.Current.Session["Region"] = obj.REGION_ID;
```

And then i create some  class , I want to get  value of session.

First , i create a class MySession.cs

```
 public class MySession
    {
        // private constructor
        private MySession()
        {
            value_group = "Group";
            //value_id = "Id";
            //value_region = "Region";
        }
        // Gets the current session.
        public static MySession Current
        {
            get
            {
                MySession session =(MySession)HttpContext.Current.Session["Group"];
                if (session == null)
                {
                    session = new MySession();
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["Group"] = session;
                }
                return session;
            }
        }
        // **** add your session properties here, e.g like this:
        public string value_group { get; set; }
        //public string value_id { get; set; }
        //public string value_region { get; set; }
    }
```

Second, i create class Test.cs and i want get value of session

```
 string value_group = MySession.Current.value_group.ToString();
                //string value_id = MySession.Current.value_id.ToString();
                //string value_region = MySession.Current.value_region.ToString();
```

But it's get error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Thank guys.

Comment: Why are you assigning `MySession` to your `HttpContext.Current.Session["Group"]`? You have previously set values in it and you want to access it. Or you don't? Please, describe what you are going to store there, what is `obj.GROUP_MOD_ID` (is it string)?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev code looks somewhat reasonable - wrapper class around access to session values - not sure why you find that code wrong. My guess with 97% probability - OP tries to access `HttpContext.Current` outside of request (i.e. in some Unit test code).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Maybe, I just don't get it. That's why I asked him a question. As for me, `value_group` is now assigned from constant value "Group", `MySession` is overwriting previously set `obj.GROUP_MOD_ID` value. I may be wrong but this is not how session values wrapper should be written :)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I see - possibly OP copy-pasted to random samples together... Looks like reasonable way to pack 3 fields into single object and use one key in session state to store it, but maybe as you read the post OP wants to read individual values from session state via wrapper ( `Current.value_region` to return `...Session["region"]` cast to its type... Not clear.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Exactly ,as Alexei Levenkov say . Can you give me some advice .

Answer (score 0):

As you said in comments, you need a wrapper class for your `Session`.

Here is how you can easily implement it. I tried to follow the code you have written at most:

```
public class MySession
{
    private const string GroupKey = "Group";
    private const string RegionKey = "Region";
    private const string IDKey = "Id";

    private static MySession _session;  
    public static MySession Current
    {
        get
        {
            return _session ?? (_session = new MySession());
        }
    }

    public string Group 
    { 
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session[GroupKey] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[GroupKey] = value;
        }
    }

    public string Region
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session[RegionKey] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[RegionKey] = value;
        }
    }

    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session[IDKey] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[IDKey] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

However, you probably don't need it. You work with only a single and current `HttpContext.Current.Session`. The values are changed dynamically and you, as I guess, want to get the actual data. Thus, your wrapper class can be a static wrapper class.

```
public static class SessionWrapper
{
    private const string GroupKey = "Group";
    private const string RegionKey = "Region";
    private const string IDKey = "Id";

    public static string Group 
    { 
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session[GroupKey] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[GroupKey] = value;
        }
    }

    public static string Region
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session[RegionKey] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[RegionKey] = value;
        }
    }

    public static string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session[IDKey] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[IDKey] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Furthermore, it is not that correct. I wouldn't do this because you are going to describe a key, getter and setter for every session property. If you add new property in session (for instance, 'Language') you will need to significantly change your `MySession` class which breaks the OCP principle.

Comment: Dear @Yeldar , I try code of you but it's not work .Debug and show error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object `  at `return HttpContext.Current.Session[GroupKey] as string;`

Comment: Alexey Levenkov was, probably, right. Are you trying to use this class outside of HTTP context? It looks like your `HttpContext.Current` is null.

Comment: Yup, read step by me above. In here , i want get value session in orther class, but it's still get error , session was created under a class of Test.aspx.cs file. Then I want to get the value of the session and used in other classes, an entirely new class. such as class ABC.cs , XYZ.cs ,.etc...

Comment: Dear @Yaldar , I have a page Login.aspx , in class Login.aspx.cs , i created session["Id"] hold user_id, session["User"] hold user_name, session["Group"] hold user_group, It`s work.
Now I create a new class, not inherrit page such as class ABC.cs , In class ABC.cs , i want to call and use value of session["Id"], session["Group"], ...etc.. But i don't known .

Thank sir.

Comment: @Headshot `Session` is a part of ASP.NET `HttpContext`. It belongs to a network user and session. It means that you only can access it during ASP.NET requests. If you call it not through the web-service, the current `HttpContext` will be null. However, if you call class `ABC` from your `Controller` then it will work as well.

Comment: @Yeldar , as you say "However, if you call class ABC from your Controller then it will work as well."  . It's mean using name of page Login.aspx  (page login.aspx in folder UI) . In class ABC.cs 
`using MyProject.UI` . What's problem ?